# How to reset all input and select fields excluding selected option in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamic form which has input and select tag .
structure of my dynamic form is

```
<form id=element_form>
   <fieldset>
      <input></input>
      <select>
        <option></option>
      </select>
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset>
     <input></input>
      <select>
        <option></option>
      </select>
  </fieldset>

</form>
```

I am using `$('#element_form').trigger("reset");` which is working fine while  `add data` in the form. but not working while updating data in the form.

so I am trying reset using :`$('#element_form fieldset input').val('')` which is ok for input but it removing select tag's first option. I need a few dropdown to not get reset.

Comment: There is no way *$('#element_form fieldset input').val('')* could remove option from select...

Comment: What does 'not working while updating data in the form' mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
$('#element_form fieldset input').val(''); // this will reset the input elements
var selectDropdowns = $('#element_form fieldset select');
$.each(selectDropdowns, function(key, eachElement) {
    if ($(eachElement).val() == "" ) {
      $(eachElement).prop('selectedIndex',0); // will reset to first index of select
    }
});
```

Comment: This logic works only when the first option in the select dropdown is empty. This logic is based on my assumption that you have the initial option in a select dropdown is empty.